# Can /etc/inittab errors prevent network startup?

Tags: networking, debian-wheezy

I have a small php server running on Raspbian via `/etc/inittab`:

```
push:235:respawn:/home/pi/volkszaehler.org/misc/tools/push-server.php
```

Due to configuration issues my php script was removed and- in consequence- init claims push-server "respawning too fast".

When this happens, the raspi does no longer establishs a network connection/ is available via network. The logon screen shows in this case:

```
[FAIL] startpar: service(s) returned failure: rc.local ... failed!
```

Is it possible that rc.local processing stops in the case before network init?

Comment: rc.local shouldn't be what starts networking. On regular Debian Wheezy at least, networking is started *much* earlier, and rc.local runs at the very end of the boot process. What makes you say that the system "no longer establishes a network connection"? What troubleshooting steps did you take to reach this conclusion, and what were the result of those?

Comment: The Raspi is attached to a FritzBox router which shows its IP. In case of error, neither ssh nor ping to that IP get a response. The network LED on the Raspi does not blink. I can see how rc.local may not be the cause but I'm stumped how inittab errors might make the device unavailable on the network.